# Sending PHP Variable from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am creating a notification checker through AJAX and PHP.

I have created an alert which is "yep" or "nope" to depend if the response is received, however neither alert is showing.

Am I sending my php variable correctly?

PHP:

```html
<?php
session_start(); 
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
  //Request identified as ajax request


   //HTTP_REFERER verification
    if($_SESSION['email'] == $_GET['email']) {

  require_once 'connect.php';


   /* FORM VARIABLES */
   $email   = strtolower($_GET['email']);

   try
   {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE to=:email");
    $stmt->execute(array(":email"=>$email));
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();

    echo $count;

   }
   catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
   }
  
  }
    else {
      header('Location: http://website.com');
    }
  }
else {
  header('Location: http://website.com');
}
?>
```

AJAX:

```js
   <script>
    function notificationCheck() {
     
     $.ajax({
      url: 'website.com/page.php?email='<? echo $email ?>,          
      data: "",
      success: function (data) {
       
       var bubification = data;
       
       if (bubification === 0) {
        
        window.alert("Yes");
        
       } else {
        
        window.alert("Nope");
        
       }
       $('#profile-sidebar-responsive-notifcation-count').html(''+bubification+'');      $('#profile-sidebar-notifcation-count').html(''+bubification+'');
      }
     });
    }

    $(document).ready(notificationCheck); 
    setInterval(notificationCheck, 10000); 
   </script>
```

Comment: I'm guessing your URL is incorrect. You need to make it absolute (eg `http://website.com/page.php?...` or relative (eg `/page.php?...`)

Comment: change <? echo $email ?> to <?php echo $email ?> If you are getting 404 error

Comment: You have answers below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. I see a sytax error in url. To concatenate a string in php you use `.` and in jquery you use `+`. You haven't concatenated your string with php blocks in url

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'website.com/page.php?email='+'<?php echo $email ?>',          
    method: "GET",
    success: function (data) {

    var bubification = data;

    if (bubification === 0) {

    window.alert("Yes");

    } else {

    window.alert("Nope");

    }
    $('#profile-sidebar-responsive-notifcation-count').html(''+bubification+'');                        $('#profile-sidebar-notifcation-count').html(''+bubification+'');
    }
});
```

Comment: Please explain why, a code dump isnt much help to anyone

Comment: The op does have a syntax error in the url, but this code creates another one. the correct syntax would be `url: 'website.com/page.php?email=<?php echo $email ?>',` there is no concatenation needed here, you are writing javascript with php

Comment: My bad I intended but forgot.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax url you are missing php

Comment: what do u mean missing php?

Comment: In the ajax URL ,  he is using <?  echo  it should have been <?php echo

Comment: then add that in your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you have concatenation error
    change

```
<? echo $email ?> to +'<?php echo $email ?>'
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP if you handling AJAX you are suppose to `echo` the response always

please remove `header('Location: http://website.com');` and use something like

```
 echo 'false'
```

Because if your `$email` is not matching you are sending that call to another page.